# Is $C_c$ dense in $L_p$ for $0<p<1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $C_c$ be the set of compactly supported functions on $\mathbb{R}$ that are infinitely differentiable. Let $S$ be the set of Schwartz functions. It is well known that $C_c$ (hence $S$) is dense in $L_p$, $p\in[1,\infty$). What can be said about the case $0<p<1$? Is $C_c$ or $S$ also dense in these spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. First show that the set of simple functions $f=\sum a_n \chi_{A_n}$ is dense, where the sum is finite and each $A_n$ is of finite measure.

Then use regularity of Lebesgue measure to find, for $A$ measurable of finite measure, compact $K$ and open $U$ with $K\subset A\subset U$ and $\mu(U\setminus K)<\epsilon$.

Using what is called **the $C^\infty$ Urysohn-Lemma**, find $f \in C_c^\infty(U)$ with $f=1$ on $K$ and $0\leq f \leq 1$.

Verify that $\Vert f -\chi_A\Vert_p$ is small.

Put the pieces together to conclude the proof.

Comment: It seems that the proof is the same as in the case $p\ge 1$. So we do not need a norm here: a quasi-norm is fine. Am I correct?

Comment: @Dony: Yes, exactly. The only place where the subadditivity (up to a constant) of the norm is used is when instead of approximating $\sum a_n \chi_{A_n}$, we just approximate $\chi_A$. This is justified because of $\Vert \sum_{n=1}^N f_n - \sum_{n=1}^N g_n\Vert_p \leq C_N \cdot \sum_{n=1}^N \Vert f_n - g_n \Vert_p$, where we can make the individual $\Vert f_n - g_n\Vert_p$ arbitrarily small.

Comment: @ PhoemueX Thank you. I just came up with another idea. I'm trying to reduce the $p<1$ case to the "p=1" case. Given $f\in L_p$, we can find a sequence of functions in $C_c^\infty$ that converges to $f^p$ in $L_1$. Then I don't how to proceed.